# Put dynamic objects to a data structure

Tags: java, android, data-structures, architecture, dataset

Is it possible to put an object (which can be any class like primitive, boxed or custom class) and get it like custom class?

For example;

```
boolean isPossible;
MyCustomClass mCustomClass;

mSet.put(isPossible);
mSet.put(mCustomClass);
```

then access it like

```
mSet.isPossible;
mSet.mCustomClass;
```

or something like that.
I need a really user friendly structure to set of objects that shared between classes.

Thanks

Comment: no, not really, because `dot` notation is calling  member of the class, as defined in the class. Once you've created the classes the only thing you can `dot` are the defined members. The best you could do is `mSet.get("isPossible")`

Comment: i already achived that as you said. What if i use code generation?

Comment: beyond my knowledge. sorry

Comment: Why bother putting it into `mSet` at all? You can access the classes as `isPossible` and `myCustomClass` without any decoration.

Comment: Because devoper can put any object to set in Runtime even not exist. And i want to him/her recover it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Visitor pattern](http://www.journaldev.com/1769/visitor-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial) can help you

This is a bit of boilerplate, but it will allow you to apply different code to objects of different types.

More modern solution is to use Scala and pattern matching.

However, you REALLY should consider sticking to couple of casts and instanceof-s.

Another solution is to put everything to single class, like Jackson's [JsonNode](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.4.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/JsonNode.html) do.

Comment: Thanks much. i research them.

Answer (score 1):

As @user1445898 stated, using casts and `instanceof`, you can use a `HashSet` of generic `Object` instances, and just cast/unbox as needed depending on what is in the set.

I just put together this simple example:

```
import java.util.HashSet;

public class HashSetTest
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();

    CustomClass myObject = new CustomClass("Custom Class Instance");

    set.add(new Integer(1));
    set.add(new Integer(2));
    set.add(new Double(3.123));
    set.add(myObject);


    for (Object o: set){
      if (o instanceof Integer){
        int i = ((Integer)o);  //unbox
        System.out.println("Integer: " + i);

      }
      else if (o instanceof Double){
        double d = ((Double)o); //unbox
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);

      }
      else if (o instanceof CustomClass){
         System.out.println("CustomClass: " + myObject);

      }
    }

  }
}

public class CustomClass
{
  private String message;

  public CustomClass(String input)
  {
    message = input;
  }
  public String toString()
  {
    return message;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
CustomClass: Custom Class Instance
Integer: 1
Integer: 2
Double: 3.123
```

Comment: To recover data, i have to forloop with this structure. And putting same type of objects make it hard to recover datas. :/ Should i go for map?

Comment: @EmreAktürk True, that is a downside.  Depending on your needs, you may want to go with another option.